# How to show that $E \left[ ( V-E[V|V+U])^2VU \right] =-2E \left[ \left( \text{Var}(V|V+U) \right)^2 \right]$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

> Let $V$ and $U$ be independent random variables (but not identical) and let 
>   \begin{align*}
> W=V+U,
> \end{align*}
>   Is it true that 
>   \begin{align}
> E \left[ ( V-E[V|W])^2 \frac{VU}{2} \right] &= - E \left[ \left(E\left[ ( V-E[V|W])^2 |W \right] \right)^2 \right]\\
> &=-E \left[ \left( Var(V|W) \right)^2 \right],
> \end{align}
>   where  $E\left[ ( V-E[V|W])^2 |W \right]= Var(V|W)$?

We can verify that this is true if $V$ and $U$ are standard normal. Since $E[V|W]= \frac{W}{2}$, on the one hand, we have 
\begin{align}
E \left[ ( V-E[V|W])^2 \frac{VU}{2} \right] = E \left[ ( V-\frac{W}{2})^2 \frac{VU}{2} \right] \\
= E \left[ ( \frac{V}{2}-\frac{U}{2})^2 \frac{VU}{2} \right] =-\frac{1}{4}.
\end{align}

On the other hand, using that $Var(V|W)= E[V^2|W]-(E[V|W])^2$ it is not difficult to show that $Var(V|W)=1/2$  and we have 
\begin{align}
-E \left[ \left( Var(V|W) \right)^2 \right]=-\frac{1}{4}.
\end{align}

There is a possibility that I am missing a constant factor. So, lets assume that both $U$ and $V$ are zero mean and unit variance (but not identically distributed).

Also, what other good examples can we use to see if it is a valid identity?

Thank you.